# Need to copy multiple columns from one spreadsheet to another based off of a drop menu selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sorry if this question has already been answered. I need to copy the information in columns A:F to a completely new spreadsheet. Once a client clicks paid from a drop menu that is in each row in column F, I would like that individual row to be moved to a new spreadsheet.  I need it to paste the information to the new sheet as each paid selection is made because there is a different function already set up to move rows between tabs based off a different checkbox.
So basically what I need is the code for this. Once the client selects paid (drop menu in column F), column A-F of that row will be copied and pasted onto a new spreadsheet. And the original spreadsheet will still have the same information (A-F) and more (G-N) on that line still and once a different client checks the checkbox in column N that row will be fully moved to the next tab which is its final home. I have tried multiple codes that I have found online but I cant get it to work with my spreadsheets. I am a complete newbie to all of this and need some of yall's expertise please! I hope this makes sense.. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your question is being downvoted by users because it show no research or attempt to solve it yourself.  Understand [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase the chances of getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function copysstoss(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='sheetname' && e.range.columnStart==6 && e.value="Paid") {
    let tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
    let tsh=tss.getSheetByName('sheetname');
    let r=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,6).getValues();
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,7,1,6).setValues(r);
  }
}
```